# Edit ForeColor list in RichText editor

Tags: richtext-editor

how could I edit my forecolor list in RichText editor, for example everytime now I have to use a custom color. By the way, I know it could be achieved by adding classes, but is there any other way ?

[image]

Comment: I tried the above method of adding the colors to the <colors> tag in ToolFile.xml Doing so removed all the default colors in the RTE and only the ones that I gave are present. Is there a way where I can keep the default colors and add my custom forecolors to the RTE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a option "add custom color" but it dissappear after closing the editor window. But you can add custom color statically.

1. Open Website\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\ToolsFile.xml
2. Find `<colors>` configuration.
3. Define required colors there. Something like:

   `<colors>
       <color value="#FF00EE" />
       <color value="#aa00EE" />
       <color value="#bb00EE" />
   </colors>`

Result is:

[image]

Comment: But also, if my sitecore client is installed under sandbox  folder, and in my source control I do not want to include that toolsFile.xml, what shall I do then ? :) What is the best practice ?